# Ubuntu 16.04/server edition: How do I setup the openvpn client to autostart?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

so I have this openvpn folder

[image]

If I manually start it via

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/my-config.conf
```

It works without any problems.

But if I use

```
service openvpn start
```

it's not connecting.

I looked at /var/log/syslog and all I can see are these:

```
Mar 31 18:41:13 yomi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
Mar 31 18:41:13 yomi systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Mar 31 18:41:13 yomi systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
Mar 31 18:41:50 yomi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
Mar 31 18:44:52 yomi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
```

I'm not sure where else to look.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the OpenVPN client, you should add the application in the "gnome-session-properties".

Just click alt+f2 and search for "gnome-session-properties". 
In the command, browse and add your application.

Hope it helps to achieve what you wanted.